# framework7 custom accordion toggle icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I copied the sample custom accordion elements from [documentation](https://framework7.io/docs/accordion.html) and just modified its icon and but I can't make the toggle of icons work.

What I want is, when the item is not expanded, it will display "+".
If expanded, it will display "-".

But right now, the plus and minus are always displayed.

Here's the screenshot: 
[image]

Elements:

Custom Accordion

```
    <div class="content-block accordion-list custom-accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <div class="accordion-item-toggle">
                <i class="f7-icons">add_round</i>
                <i class="f7-icons">delete_round</i>
                <span>Item 1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item-content">
                <p>Item 1 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <div class="accordion-item-toggle">
                <i class="f7-icons">add_round</i>
                <i class="f7-icons">delete_round</i>
                <span>Item 2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item-content">
                <p>Item 2 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Do I need to add some jquery/javascript to make this work? Or this is already included in the framework?

Comment: Please reference https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp. W3Schools goes through, step by step, on how to create an accordion.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS, which you are using could have helped but this is what I did sometime back in a similar requirement.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="accordion_container">
  <div class="accordion_head">First Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">+</span></div>
  <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
    <p>First Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_head">Second Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">+</span></div>
  <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
    <p>Second Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_head">Third Accordian Head<span class="plusminus">+</span></div>
  <div class="accordion_body" style="display: none;">
    <p>Third Accordian Body, it will have description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.accordion_container {
  width: 500px;
}

.accordion_head {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 0 1px 0;
  padding: 7px 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.accordion_body {
  background: lightgray;
}

.accordion_body p {
  padding: 18px 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.plusminus {
  float: right;
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //toggle the component with class accordion_body
  $(".accordion_head").click(function() {
    if ($('.accordion_body').is(':visible')) {
      $(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
      $(".plusminus").text('+');
    }
    if ($(this).next(".accordion_body").is(':visible')) {
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideUp(300);
      $(this).children(".plusminus").text('+');
    } else {
      $(this).next(".accordion_body").slideDown(300);
      $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');
    }
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/3amzhp6z/

Answer (score 0):

The accordion has already included in your framework named accordion.js. Your code have included html and css, now it need some js to work perfectly.

Comment: I only have `'framework7.js` and its minified version inside my `lib\framework`. Do you have any idea where to download it?

Comment: [Framework7](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/releases)
I see this download link in your document link.
Try it.